# cocos2d-x localization simplified/traditional chinese

Tags: android, iphone, localization, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

i need to separate simplified/traditional chinese. in cocos2d for iPhone, i simply use "hans" and "hant". but in cocos2d-x, i dive into the code and here is the code for CCApplication:

```
ccLanguageType ret = kLanguageEnglish;
if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"zh"])
{
    ret = kLanguageChinese;
}
else if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"en"])
{
    ret = kLanguageEnglish;
}
else if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"fr"]){
    ret = kLanguageFrench;
}
else if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"it"]){
    ret = kLanguageItalian;
}
else if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"de"]){
    ret = kLanguageGerman;
}
else if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"es"]){
    ret = kLanguageSpanish;
}
else if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"ru"]){
    ret = kLanguageRussian;
}

return ret;
```

note that only 'zh' for chinese (both simplified/traditional, maybe)

so how can i distinguish them?

EDIT: 
I use cocos2d-x and need to work with android. not just iPhone. Mickey's answer works for iPhone only. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some changes in cocos2dx android jni:
in **cocos2d-x-2.x.x/cocos2dx/platform/android/java/src/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxHelper.java**,

replace

```
return Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

with

```
return Locale.getDefault().toString();
```

Thus, you can get zh_CN, zh_TW in CCApplication::getCurrentLanguage(), also, you must update the implementations in CCApplication::getCurrentLanguage() (locates cocos2d-x-2.x.x/cocos2dx/platform/android/CCApplication.cpp):

```
ccLanguageType CCApplication::getCurrentLanguage()
{
    std::string languageName = getCurrentLanguageJNI();
    if (languageName.find("zh_CN") == 0) {
        return kLanguageChineseCN; // need define this value by yourself
    } else if (languageName.find("zh_TW") == 0) {
        return kLanguageChineseTW; // need define this value by yourself
    } else if (languangeName.find("en") == 0) {
        return kLanguageEnglish;
    } ...

    return kLanguageEnglish;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following code on cocos2D helloworld. I can seperate simplified/traditional by **zh-Hans** and **zh-Hant**.

Step1. In HelloWorldLayer.m, you need to add this line at the top or fail to compile :

```
#import <Foundation/NSLocale.h>
```

Step2. Now, you can get language. For example,

```
-(id)init{
    NSString* currentLang = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] ;
    NSLog(@"Language: %@", currentLang);
}
```

Comment: i use cocos2d-x, not cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I modified cocos2d-x code to distinguish simplified and traditional Chinese. Note, this is for cocos2d-x v3.0+.

For iOS, modify cocos2d_libs.xcodeproj/platform/ios/CCApplication-ios.mm

```
LanguageType Application::getCurrentLanguage()
{
    // get the current language and country config
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];

    // get the current language code.(such as English is "en", Chinese is "zh" and so on)
    NSDictionary* temp = [NSLocale componentsFromLocaleIdentifier:currentLanguage];
    NSString * languageCode = [temp objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];

    LanguageType ret = LanguageType::ENGLISH;
    if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"zh"])
    {
       /** CHANGE THE FOLLOWING LINES */
        NSString* scriptCode = [temp objectForKey:NSLocaleScriptCode];
        NSString* countryCode = [temp objectForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode];
        // On iOS, either chinese hong kong or chinese taiwan are traditional chinese.
        if ([scriptCode isEqualToString:@"Hant"] || [countryCode isEqualToString:@"HK"] || [countryCode isEqualToString:@"TW"]) {
            ret = LanguageType::CHINESE_TRADITIONAL;  // You need to add these enum values to LanguageType
        } else {
            ret = LanguageType::CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED;  // You need to add these enum values to LanguageType
        }
    }
    else if ([languageCode isEqualToString:@"en"])
    {
        ret = LanguageType::ENGLISH;
    }
.....
.....
```

For Android , modify cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/CCApplication-android.cpp

```
LanguageType Application::getCurrentLanguage()
{
    std::string languageName = getCurrentLanguageJNI();
    const char* pLanguageName = languageName.c_str();
    const char* languageCode = getCurrentLanguageCode();
    LanguageType ret = LanguageType::ENGLISH;

    if (0 == strcmp("zh", languageCode))
    {
        /** Change the following lines */
        if (languageName.find("TW") != std::string::npos) {
            ret = LanguageType::CHINESE_TRADITIONAL;
        } else {
            ret = LanguageType::CHINESE_SIMPLIFIED;
        }
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp("en", languageCode))
    {
        ret = LanguageType::ENGLISH;
    }
    else if (0 == strcmp("fr", languageCode))
.....
.....
```

and also modify libcocos2d/org/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxHelper.java

```
public static String getCurrentLanguage() {
    // This would return language code as well as region code, e.g. zh_CN
    return Locale.getDefault().toString();
}
```

Comment: There's an error in the code, when you check to compare the code you should be looking for a country code of either TW or HK to consider it traditional Chinese. Hans is the one for simplified. (For the iOS version). And shouldn't you be looking for HK in the languageName for the android version as well?

Comment: @Chiquis is right. iOS condition should be updated to [scriptCode isEqualToString:@"Hant"] || [countryCode isEqualToString:@"HK"] || [countryCode isEqualToString:@"TW"]

Comment: Thanks Chiquis and BoJIHa, I've updated the condition in iOS. For Android, no need to check for the substring HK, since there's only zh_rCN and zh_rTW to distinguish simplified chinese vs traditional chinese.